# How to create Tabbed Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have implemented navigation drawer in android which has 5 fragments on clicking drawer items,in any one of my fragment i want to implement tabbed fragments(3> more tabs) can anybody tell me how to do it ?

Comment: http://www.paulusworld.com/technical/android-navigationdrawer-sliding-tabs .. try this

Comment: Making android sliding tabs inside a fragment is very similar to making it inside an activity, but i think you need to do a few things like make your fragment as a FragmentActivity and also add most logic to your main activity instead of the fragment class.

Comment: Please will u tel how to do it?? send me codes please

Comment: thank u @SukhwantSinghGrewal tat was helpful to some extent but not wat i actually needed

Comment: See this one I have Navigation Drawer and on selecting one item i need to go to another fragment where i have inserted tabs to that fragment. The Problem is i cant able to do that with by Extending Fragment plss help My code posted below.. Getting error in TabbedFragment.java in that getSupportFragmentManager() method.

Comment: MainActivity.java    private void displayView(int position) {
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
            fragment= new HomeFragment();
   break;
  case 1:
            fragment = new MarkFragment();
   break;
  case 2:
   fragment = new PagesFragment();
   break;
  case 3:
            fragment =new TabbedFragment(); //on click of this one 
            break;
  case 4:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
   break;
  case 5:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
   break;